# Sorting in Python with int as input

Tags: python

I have user entered numbers but when I entered in descending order then only list is sorted else it's not.

```
values = input("Enter the number")
values1 = input("Enter the number")
values2 = input("Enter the number")
templist = values.split(","),values1.split(","),values2.split(",")
print('List : ',templist)
finallist = sorted(templist)
print('Final List : ',finallist)
```

Comment: Please show your input values!

Comment: You need to show an example input and expected input, its hard to see what your trying to do here. In other words, you need to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `templist` is not a list. Its a tuple containing lists (you even print it). Here lies the probable start of your issues.

Answer (score 0):

When you use sorted(templist) you tuple of lists gets sorted and not the inner list!

You need to iterate through your inner list and sort them separately like,

```
map(sorted,templist)
```

or

```
[sorted(l) for l in templist]
```

That is,

```
>>> values = input("Enter the number")
Enter the number"5,4,3,2,1"
>>> values1 = input("Enter the number")
Enter the number"9,8,7,6"
>>> values2 = input("Enter the number")
Enter the number"8,6,4,2"
>>> templist = values.split(","),values1.split(","),values2.split(",")
>>> templist
(['5', '4', '3', '2', '1'], ['9', '8', '7', '6'], ['8', '6', '4', '2'])
>>> print('List : ',templist)
('List : ', (['5', '4', '3', '2', '1'], ['9', '8', '7', '6'], ['8', '6', '4', '2']))
>>> sorted(templist)
[['5', '4', '3', '2', '1'], ['8', '6', '4', '2'], ['9', '8', '7', '6']]
>>>
>>> map(sorted,templist)
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['6', '7', '8', '9'], ['2', '4', '6', '8']]
>>>
>>> #or
... 
>>> [sorted(l) for l in templist]
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['6', '7', '8', '9'], ['2', '4', '6', '8']]
```

This is sorting list of strings.

If you want to sort list of integers,

```
>>> [sorted(int(n) for n in l) for l in templist]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8]]
```